# how to access array of objects in javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, object

```
const thumbnail = [
  {url: "https://randomUrlForImages.com"},
  {url: "https://randomUrlForImages2.com"}
]
```

I want to access url for displaying image
I'm using
 `<img src = {thumbnail.url} />`
and its not working.
also tried using `{thumbnail.0.url}`
`{thumbnail"[url]"}`

Comment: Please spend 2 minutes googling before asking a question `thumbnail[0].url`

Comment: `thumbnail[0]['url']` also works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When facing these issues try consoling the values you try to get...
Like here you can try

```
console.log(thumbnail[0].url)
```

or you can also use `console.log(thumbnail[0]["url"])`

if this works then you can delete the console logs and use it in the image code...